# Checking if from two given lists, one is a cyclic permutation of the other

Tags: python, loops, cyclic

Looking for advice on whether or not my code and idea are effective or I should be trying a different method. I'm not looking for full answers, rather hints. A simple "Keep going/trying" or "try something else" will suffice.

I have two parameters with the function, both are lists. They need to be of equal length to be compared, otherwise the program returns False.

An object in index `i` is moved to index `(i+m)%k`, where `k` is the length of the list, and `m` is how much the item in index `i` has moved.

My idea is this:

From the two lists of length `k`, I will check each index individually, and if it finds that the index has been moved `(i+m)%k`, it will add `1` to the counter.

There are 3 possibilities of cyclic permutations for a list of size 3, so if the counter hits `3`, it will return a `True`.

```
def cyclic(lst1, lst2):
    number_success = 0
    if len(lst1) == len(lst2):  # checks to see if lists are equal length
        for i in range(len(lst1)): # starts with i index to check each spot
            for j in range(len(lst1)):  # starts with j index to test cycling
                if lst1[i] == lst2[(i+j)%len(lst1)]:
                    number_success += 1
                else:
                    continue
        if number_success == len(lst1):
            return(True)
        else:
            return(False)
    else:
        print("idiot")
```

Comment: This will return True if the elements in the lists match, independent of how they are ordered, as the if check is done outside both loops.

Comment: I didn't know about cyclic permutations and went to do some brief reading about it; are you sure a list of 3 has 3 possible cyclic permutations? Wouldn't they be `{1,2}`, `{2,3}`, `{1,3}` and `{1,2,3}` (4 possibilities)?

Comment: @Adirio You're correct. It seems to be working only for lists of length 3. Throwing in a list with length 4 gives me the wrong return

Comment: @lucasnadalutti only checking for numbers that are in the lists

Comment: @RonaldB try to indent one more these 2 lines: `if number_succes == len(lst1):` and `return(True)`. The else clause leave it as is.

Comment: @RonaldB and you also need to swap i and j loops

Comment: @Adirio I understand now what I've done wrong. I've done is checked for different patterns separately, instead of looking for a certain pattern once, and if I cant find that pattern, search for another pattern.

Comment: @RonaldB look at my answer below and see what I've done

Comment: `print("idiot")` what a user friendly

Comment: @Gabriel that's directed towards me if I forget to put in lists of equal length!

Comment: Are you just checking to see if the two lists represent (are) a cyclic permutation? Or are you finding all the permutations of ```lst1```; then checking each permutation?

Comment: Checking if one list is a cyclic permutation of the other

Answer (score 2):

How about concatenate lst1 with itself, then check if lst2 is found in lst1?
As an illustration using strings:

```
lst1="1234"
lst2="2341"
if lst2 in lst1+lst1:
    print "yup"
else:
    print "nope"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Corrected code in question:**

```
def cyclic(lst1, lst2):
    number_success = 0
    if len(lst1) == len(lst2):  # checks to see if lists are equal length
        for j in range(len(lst1)): # starts with j index to test cycling
            for i in range(len(lst1)):  # starts with i index to check each spot
                if lst1[i] == lst2[(i+j)%len(lst1)]:
                    number_success += 1
            if number_success == len(lst1):
                return True
        return False
    else:
        print("idiot")
```

Comment: Hi Adirio, while I appreciate the fix and will thumbs it up, I just wanted a minor suggestion or a poke in the right direction. I won't be looking at the code or using it, but I trust that you are a capable programmer and that is indeed that the solution.

Comment: @RonaldB This can be further improved, for example counting the number of matches and returning True is less efficient that breaking the inner loop if you find a miss-match

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm will not work.  You are comparing every item in `lst1` with every item in `lst2` and accumulating the *matches*. Your approach doesn't account for the order of the items.  You are essentially doing

```
set(lst1) == set(lst2)
```

I added a print statement in the inner loop to *watch* what was happening.  I have found printing variables, calculation and comparison results effective when trying to figure out what I am doing.

```
print(lst1[i], lst2[(i+j)%len(lst1)], lst1[i] == lst2[(i+j)%len(lst1)])
```

---

You can check by comparing the two lists, if they are equal then there is a cycle, if they are not equal, rotate one list and repeat, if after len(list) rotations there isn't a match then there isn't a cycle.  Something like this

... code deleted ...

Answer (score 0):

How about recycling the list2 to list1 and check

```py
def cyclic(list1, list2):
    if set(list1) != set(list2):
        return False
    elem01_idx = list2.index(list1[0])
    recycled_list2 = list2[elem01_idx:] + list2[:elem01_idx]
    return list1 == recycled_list2
    
    

list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [2,3,4,1]

print(cyclic(list1, list2))
# True
```